# kafka producer create too many zookeeper connections

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I find my kafka producer create many zookeeper connections

```
ss -anop | grep 2181 | wc -l
```

I have count how many connections it has , there are more then 2000 !
my zookeeper config like this :

```
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
maxClientCnxns=1024
```

I think it is not normal  .

Comment: would probably be better answered on http://askubuntu.com/ or similar no?

Comment: I think you need to specify your question. Do you want a fix or you want understand a reason or what?